# Make colors represent individual point instead of area in Plotly Densitymapbox

Tags: python, plotly

I've got some kind of Densitymapbox plot, plotted by this code:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Densitymapbox(
    lon=x,
    lat=y,
    z=floors,
    radius=10,
    colorscale="plasma"
))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map", mapbox_center_lon=37.52, mapbox_center_lat=55.75)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, width = 800, height = 700)
fig.show()
```

It looks like this:
[image: Plot]

But there is a problem. Colorbar goes up to 70 and points in center are yellow as if they were near 70 too. Thing is they are mostly very small, about 10, so this yellow color appears to be some kind of sum of them instead of representing individual point. How do I change this behavior and make plotly color it based on individual colors?

Comment: If I remove biggest and rarest points which have "z" value > 40, it becomes even worse: color doesn't represent "z" value even near, every place with a lot of points placed near just becomes yellow.

Comment: Have you considered using a scattermapbox trace instead? Summing is basically what densitymapbox is for...

Answer (score 1):

Well, as @nicolaskruchten said, I gust picked wrong plot type. Use Scattermapbox instead.